# null object reference of TextView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I have two fragments and a main activity. The first fragment, FriendsFragment (extends ListFragment) is displayed on the screen and when the user clicks an item, the main Activity replaces the FriendsFragment with FeedFragment, then calls a method from FeedFragment to update the textView.

I'm getting an error that the textView object in the FeedFragment class is null even though I instantiate using the `findViewById` method.

I have looked at related questions and have tried the solutions but nothing is working. I've tried doing `getView().findViewById(R.id.feed_view)`, `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.feed_view)`, and I've tried putting these in `onActivityCreated()` and `onCreateView()`

The only thing that worked is writing this code in onActivityCreated():

```
text = getView().findViewById(R.id.feed_view); 
text.setText("some string");
```

but this is not what I want

FeedFragments.java

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    private static String TAG = "Feed Fragment";
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered FeedFragment.java onActivityCreated()");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered FeedFragment.java onCreateView()");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container,false);;
    text = v.findViewById(R.id.feed_view);
    return v;
}

public void updateDisplay(int position)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "FeedFragment.java: updateDisplay()");
    text.setText(position);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
// previously declared feedFragment: feedFragment = new FeedFragment(); 
public void onItemSelected(int position)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onItemSelected(" + position + ")");
    fragManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedFragment, "feed_fragment");
    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragTransaction.commit();

    feedFragment.updateDisplay(position);
}
```

fragment_feed.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/greeting" />

</ScrollView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onViewcreated() is being called after updateDisplay() because the system doesn't run it right away.

you need to pass a value to the feedFragment on it's creation and store it in a bundle and retrieve it after the fragment internal code is run by the system.

the way you solve it is like this:

when you instantiate feedFragment you do it like this:

```
feedFragment = FeedFragment.newInstance(position)
```

and inside FeedFragment class you should have a static code:

```
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

public static FeedFragment newInstance(int param1) {
    FeedFragment fragment = new FeedFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and non static code:

```
private int mParam1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
    }
} 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered FeedFragment.java onCreateView()");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container,false);;
    text = v.findViewById(R.id.feed_view);
    text.setText(String.valueOf(mParam1));
    return v;
}
```

I wrapped mParam1 in String.valueOf() because when you pass integer to setText it thinks you try to use a Strings.xml resource instead of the number you chose.

also I used very generic variable names. please change them to something meaningful so that your code makes sense.

Comment: so you are not using my updateDisplay() method at all? when does onCreateView() get called? If i choose a different item in the list will this code still work? i'm still learning the backstack portion so I am not able to test this yet

Comment: once you run  fragTransaction.commit(); there is a bunch of async code being run by the system. after it is done (there is no way to know how long it will take) onCreateView will be called. (usualy it's very fast but not instant, maybe a few hundred miliseconds maybe even less. im not sure)

once it finished, you should be able to use updateDisplay() , but only if you don't reload the fragment,

Comment: your code works, but I'm just confused why setText isn't working in updateDisplay()...any idea? it's still throwing a null exception. I have seen similar questions and it seemed to work for other people.

Comment: sure. understranding this is the key to working with fragments effectively. 
setText isn't working in updateDisplay() because you are calling updateDisplay() inside of onItemSelected() that contains the fragTransaction.commit() command, it will only work if you will run updateDisplay() after waiting for the fragment to finish loading.

Comment: ohh, that makes sense and made me realize that I forgot to add the getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions(); line of code after committing the fragment transaction. now it works, thank you so much.

Comment: Yes that would solve your issue, but I would recommend not using getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions(); too much. 

from my past experience, if you use it a lot especially when you have complex fragment logic, it can make your app feel unresponsive,